# How to merge last four columns of a text file while inserting a different delimiter?

Tags: linux, text-processing

I have a file:

```
sample_1   sample_2   sample_3   category   subcategory   class   levels
52         59         80         wild       animal        herbe   small
25         65         71         pet        insect
```

I want to merge all the column after third column to get my desirable output:

```
sample_1   sample_2   sample_3   info         
52         59         80         wild|animal|herbe|small
25         65         71         pet|insect
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following awk script:

```
awk 'BEGIN { IFS=OFS="\t" }
     NR==1 { print "sample_1" OFS "sample_2" OFS "sample_3" OFS "info" }
     NR >1 { four=$4
             for(i=5; i <= NF; i++) four=four"|"$i
             print $1 OFS $2 OFS $3 OFS four }' input
```

The script has three sections:

1. `BEGIN` -- before the script reads any input, it sets the input- and output- field separator to be a TAB.
2. `NR==1` -- this rewrites the header as you've shown.
3. `NR >1` -- this collapses fields four onwards to be combined with tabs (OFS). It does this by initializing the new value with field #4; it then loops over the remaining fields and appends their values with the pipe character. Once the loop is done, it prints the reassembled line.

Comment: Thankyou, it is working.

Comment: Why `print a OFS b` instead of `print a, b`?

Comment: @SethMMorton because I'm only modestly competent at awk and this felt most obvious to me. Since OFS is custom here, I like that the repetition draws attention there.

Answer (score 0):

Quick'n'dirty with GNU sed, provided none of your lines has trailing whitespace:

```
$ sed -E -e 's/\s+/\|/4g' -e '1s/\S*$/info/' file
sample_1   sample_2   sample_3   info
52         59         80         wild|animal|herbe|small
25         65         71         pet|insect
```

If lines *do* have trailing whitespace, you can remove it first:

```
sed -E -e 's/ +$//' -e 's/\s+/\|/4g' -e '1s/\S*$/info/' file
```

Comment: Sorry, but this command is adding extra '|' at the end of some lines:               
 25         65         71         pet|insect|

Comment: @AnjaliChaudhary so those lines *do* have trailing whitespace - to use this method you will need to remove it first. See my edit for a suggestion how.

Answer (score -1):

Tried with below command and it worked fine

```
awk 'NR >1{$4=$4$5$6$7;$5=$6=$6=$7="";print $0}' filename| sed '1i sample_1   sample_2   sample_3   info '| awk '{printf "%s%10s%10s%30s\n",$1,$2,$3,$4}'
```

output

```
sample_1  sample_2  sample_3            info
52        59        80          wildanimalherbesmall
25        65        71                     petinsect
```

Comment: Note that the question requested `|` symbols between the fields, and that this solution hard-codes a maximum of 7 fields.